# FirstIn and LastOut in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, telerik

I have a table name [EmployeeAttendance] and I have records in it in respective order.

```
SELECT EI.[FirstName]+' '+EI.[LastName] [EmployeeName], [Dpt].[FullName] [Department], [Desig].[FullName] [Designation], FirstIN   = CAST(MIN([AttendanceTimeIn]) AS TIME), LastOUT   = CAST(MAX([AttendanceTimeOut]) AS TIME), HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(MIN(AttendanceTimeIn) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(AttendanceTimeOut) AS TIME))  
FROM [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [EI],  [HRM].[tbl_Designation] [Desig], [HRM].[tbl_Department] [Dpt], [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance] [Attendance]
WHERE [Dpt].[ID] = [EI].[DeptCode] AND [Desig].[ID] = [EI].[DesignationCode] AND [Attendance].[EmpCode] = [EI].[ID] AND [EI].[RecordStatusCode] != '13'
AND CAST([AttendanceTimeIn] as date) = CAST(GetDate()-1 as Date)
GROUP BY
EI.[FirstName]+' '+EI.[LastName], [Dpt].[FullName], [Desig].[FullName], CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS DATE)
```

This is what I am getting as output.

```
Ajmal John      Projects            Project Associate   10:16:38.0000000    NULL    NULL
Asif Asif       Office Staff        Office Boy               09:28:36.0000000   NULL    NULL
Muhammad Asim   Support             Database Support Engineer 10:47:28.0000000  19:16:17.0000000    9
Sajjad Ahmed    Projects            Project Manager          09:41:34.0000000   NULL    NULL
Sidra Khizar    Quality Assurance   SQA Engineer        10:18:48.0000000    NULL    NULL
```

Because I have placed TimeIn and TimeOut in same row it is giving me TimeOut but as for other fields I have Time Out in 2nd row so it is giving Null. Not sure why

Comment: you're missing `GROUP BY EmpId` at the end

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze Yeah I added but now I am getting only FirstIn but not LastOut

Comment: what are the datatypes of the TImeIn and TimeOut columns?

Comment: The data type is datetime

Comment: Try removing `CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS DATE)` from the GROUP BY or adding this to the SELECT

Comment: I tried this already but it will only add an extra column of TimeIn and isn't affecting anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163031/discussion-between-doonie-darkoo-and-cool-br33ze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TimeIn and TimeOut are of `TIME` datatype then this works

```
DECLARE @EmployeeAttendance TABLE (EmpID INT, TimeIn TIME, [TimeOut] TIME);

INSERT INTO @EmployeeAttendance
(EmpID, TimeIn, TimeOut)
SELECT 1, '9:00', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL, '11:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '11:30', NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL,'13:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'13:30', NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,NULL,'18:00';

SELECT
    EmpID
    , FirstIN   = MIN([TimeIn])
    , LastOUT   = MAX([TimeOut])
    , HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, MIN(TimeIn), MAX(TimeOut))
    --, MAX([TimeOut])-MIN([TimeIn]) AS HoursSpent
FROM
    @EmployeeAttendance
GROUP BY
    EmpID;
```

Output

[image]

If the columns are `DATETIME` then try this

```
DECLARE @EmployeeAttendance TABLE (EmpID INT, TimeIn DATETIME, [TimeOut] DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @EmployeeAttendance
(EmpID, TimeIn, TimeOut)
SELECT 1, '9:00', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL, '11:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '11:30', NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL,'13:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'13:30', NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,NULL,'18:00';

SELECT
    EmpID
    , FirstIN   = CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME)
    , LastOUT   = CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME)
    , HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(MIN(TimeIn) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(TimeOut) AS TIME))
    --, MAX([TimeOut])-MIN([TimeIn]) AS HoursSpent
FROM
    @EmployeeAttendance
GROUP BY
    EmpID;
```

Comment: The datatype is datetime for both fields and I tried your query but didn;t work out for me

Comment: I've added another sample answer below using DATETIME

Comment: This is going crazy I don't understand why it is happening, When I put the timeout in the same row it works fine but when I put the timeout in another row it gives null

Comment: in my example TimeIn and TimeOut are on separate rows and the TSQL works

Comment: Yes I've seen that and that's what I'm curious about. I still can't figure out a way to do that.

Comment: I put them on separate rows as your sample data showed them that way

Comment: Why should it? I've shown examples with TIME and DATETIME and you said the datetype you're using is DATETIME.  Post your tsql

Comment: Let me edit my question and I will put all the result set and query in there

Answer (score 2):

If Your Data Type Is TIME, then this works fine

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
    ([EmpID] int, [TimeIn] TIME, [TimeOut] TIME)
;

INSERT INTO @T
    ([EmpID], [TimeIn], [TimeOut])
VALUES
    (1, '9:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '11:00'),
    (1, '11:30', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '13:00'),
    (1, '13:30', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '18:00')
;
;WITH TM
AS
(
SELECT
    EmpID, 
    MIN([TimeIn]) as StartTime,
    MAX([TimeOut]) as EndTime
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY EmpId
)
SELECT
    *,
    HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
    FROM TM
```

Result

[image]

If The DataType is different Try Casting it as Time inside the MAX and MIN Functions

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `TimeIn`  & `TimeOut` as DateTime field in SQL server then it can be achieved as below:

```
SELECT
  EmpID, 
  MIN(cast(TimeIN as time)) as FirstIN,
  MAX(cast(TimeOut as time)) as LastOUT,
  DATEDIFF(hour,MIN([TimeIn]),MAX([TimeOut])) AS HoursSpent
FROM [EmployeeAttendance]
GROUP BY EmpId
```

Query gives output for above sample data is as follows:

```
EmpID   FirstIN             LastOUT             HoursSpent
1       09:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000    9
```